# angular form.io builder how to customize list of components and list of attribute per component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, web-component, formio

I am using form.io and angular 10.

I was able to create a demo project of form.io in the angular cli .

I was also able to create a **custom component** as well and set my own editForm  for the component.

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { FormioCustomComponentInfo, registerCustomFormioComponent } from 'angular-formio';
import { AggridWrapperComponent } from './aggrid-wrapper.component';

export function minimalEditForm() {
  return {
    components: [
      { key: 'type', type: 'hidden' },
      {
        weight: 0,
        type: 'textfield',
        input: true,
        key: 'label',
        label: 'Label',
        placeholder: 'Label',
        validate: {
          required: true,
        },
      },
      {
        weight: 10,
        type: 'textfield',
        input: true,
        key: 'key',
        label: 'Field Code',
        placeholder: 'Field Code',
        tooltip: 'The code/key/ID/name of the field.',
        validate: {
          required: true,
          maxLength: 128,
          pattern: '[A-Za-z]\\w*',
          patternMessage:
            'The property name must only contain alphanumeric characters, underscores and should only be started by any letter character.',
        },
      },
      {
        weight: 20,
        type: 'textfield',
        input: true,
        key: 'customOptions.myOption',
        label: 'My Custom Option',
        placeholder: 'My Custom Option',
        validate: {
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}
const COMPONENT_OPTIONS: FormioCustomComponentInfo = {
  type: 'myaggrid',
  selector: 'my-grid',
  editForm:minimalEditForm,
  title: 'agGrid',
  group: 'basic',
  icon: 'fa fa-star',
};


export function registerAgGridComponent(injector: Injector) {
  registerCustomFormioComponent(COMPONENT_OPTIONS, AggridWrapperComponent, injector);

}
```

Overall the form.io builder gives a lot of components to drag and drop .

But in fact I need a small number of components and in each component reduce the number of attributes/properties or set my own properties.

I try like this but not work

```
<form-builder [form]='{
    "title": "My Test Form",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true,
            "tableView": true,
            "inputType": "text",
            "inputMask": "",
            "label": "First Name",
            "key": "firstName",
            "placeholder": "Enter your first name",
            "prefix": "",
            "suffix": "",
            "multiple": false,
            "defaultValue": "",
            "protected": false,
            "unique": false,
            "persistent": true,
            "validate": {
                "required": true,
                "minLength": 2,
                "maxLength": 10,
                "pattern": "",
                "custom": "",
                "customPrivate": false
            },
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": null,
                "eq": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "textfield",
            "input": true,
            "tableView": true,
            "inputType": "text",
            "inputMask": "",
            "label": "Last Name",
            "key": "lastName",
            "placeholder": "Enter your last name",
            "prefix": "",
            "suffix": "",
            "multiple": false,
            "defaultValue": "",
            "protected": false,
            "unique": false,
            "persistent": true,
            "validate": {
                "required": true,
                "minLength": 2,
                "maxLength": 10,
                "pattern": "",
                "custom": "",
                "customPrivate": false
            },
            "conditional": {
                "show": "",
                "when": null,
                "eq": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "input": true,
            "label": "Submit",
            "tableView": false,
            "key": "submit",
            "size": "md",
            "leftIcon": "",
            "rightIcon": "",
            "block": false,
            "action": "submit",
            "disableOnInvalid": true,
            "theme": "primary",
            "type": "button"
        }
    ]
}' (change)="onChange($event)" language="he"></form-builder>
```

How can i define my own list of components and configure attribures/properties in each components?

Answer (score 1):

By using the [option] attribute in form-builder it is possible to determine the list of components and also change the language.

example in [angular-formio set language in FormBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667350/angular-formio-set-language-in-formbuilder)

Comment: Were you able to configure attribures/properties in each components?